# Adding case history to the Case object

Tags: case, history-tracking, case-object

I have seen case history as related list on the contact record. I would like to know how we can add the case history as related list on the case record.

Comment: Refer this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/tracking_field_history_for_standard_objects.htm

Answer (score 2):

From your 'answer' on your question that includes screenshots, the related list that your client is seeing when looking at the detail page for a `Contact` has nothing to do with history tracking.

The `Cases` related list that appears on a `Contact` is simply the Cases related list. It is not showing any history of the case, but rather the current state of a related case.

What you are asking for is, strictly speaking, not possible.

If you had a self-relationship field (i.e. a lookup to `Case` on the `Case` object), you could have a similar related list appear on the Case, but I doubt that is what your client is asking for.

What I believe your client is asking for, based on the small amount of description that you've given us, is to see a summarized view of the case, displayed on the case itself...which makes very little sense.

You could achieve something similar using a custom visualforce page, but again, why would you (or rather, your client) want to display the exact same data on the same page, twice?

I highly recommend that you have a conversation with your client to determine what they actually need (because what they've asked for makes no sense, much like the video [the expert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg) on youtube).

If you don't clarify requirements and set expectations (i.e. just nodding and saying 'yes' to everything the client says), both parties will end up disappointed.

Comment: Hello Derek, Thanks for the feedback. My client is new to Salesforce. They are using cases object and what they want is like for example, when they open a case record they would like to see how many times the contact has contacted them, the number of cases they have got for that contact like cases, case status, last interaction etc. Does this make sense? This is as far I can get from them.

Answer (score 1):

On Case Layout add following related list:

[image]

Case Layout can be found in Setup > Customize > Case > Page Layouts

Comment: Same way you can add it to Case records. There is no difference. Navigate to Case Layout by Setup > Customize > Case > Page Layouts  @LMK

Answer (score 0):

[Add the Related List Component to Your Lightning Pages](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_comp_related_list.htm) from Spring 17 Release Notes is describing very similar to what you are asking here, available in Lightning Experience.

> With the Related List component, your users can focus on the things
>   that matter most. For example, you can use this component to display
>   activity history front-and-center on all case pages. You can even
>   configure this component to display a related list for a parent
>   record. Say that you want your users to know if a case’s contact has
>   any other open cases. Your users will never miss a beat.